# Bash script , error output redirection

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, error-handling

I want to redirect the error

```
python: can't open file '/usr/bin/file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I used this command

```
python /usr/bin/file 2> /dev/zero
```

but this is hiding all the output in my file , so I want to redirect only the not found error and nothing else .

Binary file is scripted by me through python giving this

```
Enter your password:
Welcome User :)
Checking your Secure Code now ...
Secure Code OK , Enjoy !!

What is the folder path ? ### This is hidden when used the code ###
```

Comment: same thing my script output has been hidden as well

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the system binary `/usr/bin/file` and why is it missing?

Comment: @tripleee check the edited you can see what is being hidden when i used the command

Answer (score 1):

You want `/dev/null`, not `/dev/zero`, which is a generator for scripts (you can read it for an endless stream of zero bytes if you ever need one).

The syntax you show does in fact redirect only standard error; if standard output is lost, it's because of something else.